# bose library is using old chromedriver version (114)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm using **bose** python library and it is using old chromedriver version - 114.
I checked it is downloading the correct version of chromedriver but not sure why it is using old version.
What I suspect is that the latest version of chromedriver is 114 here - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Error Message:
`from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 119.0.6045.199`

FYI I'm trying to run this repo.
https://github.com/omkarcloud/g2-scraper

Thanks for your help in advance!

I tried to run this repo but no luck so far.
https://github.com/omkarcloud/g2-scraper

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer Here, Updated Repository which fixes this issue, use it at https://github.com/omkarcloud/g2-scraper

Answer (score 0):

I check this repo, and found it used a name of packget is bose. I found it in [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/bose/) which can simplify our selenium initialization operations.

Your error is your local chrome's version is 119... ,but may be bose packget defualt version is 114...., so you should focus on BrowserConfig's args: aexecutable_path' or something.